# Blank screen when trying to inject a service

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am trying to create an ionic2 application that gets data using http requests. I started of with ExampleProject with the command

```
ionic start ExampleProject blank --v2 --ts.
```

I added a service using the command, `ionic g provider QuerySEService`. Once done, I imported the service in my app.ts and home.ts files. When I try to add the service as parameter to my home.ts file, I get a blank screen in windows & android .
If I don't use service in the constructor parameter the works fine.**This is just template app. It does not do anything with the service.**
I am unable to understand why the app does not inject the service into home.ts constructor. Please find the code below. I executed the code using Visual studio 2015 as well through the command

```
ionic emulate windows
```

**app.ts;**

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';


import {HomePage} from './pages/home/home';
import {QuerySeService} from './providers/query-se-service/query-se-service';


@App({
    template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
    providers: [QuerySeService],
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}
```

**home.ts:**

```
import {Page, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { QuerySeService } from '../../providers/query-se-service/query-se-service';

@Page( {
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor( private service: QuerySeService ) {
    }
}
```

**query-se-service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

/*
  Generated class for the QuerySeService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class QuerySeService {
    constructor( private http: Http ) { }
}
```

This is the structure of the code.

[image]

This is what I get when I run the application.
[image]

When service is not injected into home.ts, this is what I get.

[image]

**Update**
I asked this question in ionic's forum as well and got a reply that [Angular 2 RC release is still not supported by Ionic 2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/blank-screen-when-trying-to-inject-a-service/51569/4?u=jagansai).

Comment: whats in the error log of the browser?

Comment: Surprisingly there is none. I ran it on mobile emulator.

Comment: Updated the question with the reply from ionic moderator in ionic forum